# cmd file to Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script in as a cmd file

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (myservices.txt) DO (
echo "Start service: %%G”
NET START "%%G" 
)
```

How would I translate that into powershell?

My guess would be something like this

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (myservice.txt) DO (
echo "Start service: %%G”
start-service -name "%%G" 
)
```

Comment: can you share a sample of `gps_services.txt`

Comment: it is just a text file with the name of the service

Answer (score 2):

If `gsp_services.txt` contains service name on each line:

```
   get-content gps_services.txt | % { 
       "Start service: $_”
       start-service $_
    }
```

Comment: Simpler: `Get-Content gps_services.txt | Start-Service -Verbose`

Comment: That is not exactly the same, right, since message is not customizable. I just wanted to point that out :)